# Use a Tkinter Entry for calculations and store as variable

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am creating a calculator using drop-down menus in my code.  I have two drop-down options and some entries.

```py
root = tk.Tk()

plans = {
    'Maintain': '0',
    'Fat Loss': '-500', 
    'Muscle Gain': '350'
}

levels = {
    'Low': '12',
    'Low Medium': '13',
    'Medium': '14',
    'Medium High': '15',
    'High': '16'
}

plan = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a plan:', justify=tk.RIGHT)
plan.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=5)
plan_var = tk.StringVar(root)
plan_var.set('Maintain')
plan_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, plan_var, *plans)
plan_dropdown.grid(column=4, row=5)

agg = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a level: ', justify=tk.RIGHT)
agg.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=7)
maint_var = tk.StringVar(root)
maint_var.set('Low')
maint_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, maint_var, *levels)
maint_dropdown.grid(column=4, row=7)
```

So I want to write a function that would calculate `plan_var` selection (so either `-500` or `350`) added to `maint_var` selection (from `12` to `16`, included)".

```py
def calculate():
   calories_total = int(plan_var.get()) + int(maint_var.get())*int(bw_entry.get())
   print(calories_total)

submit = tk.Button(root, text='Calculate', command=calculate)
submit.grid(column=4, row=9)

root.mainloop()
```

I know my calculate function is wrong and missing something, just not sure how to write it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your dictionaries a dictionary of integers so you don't need to do conversions when calculating and also assign a value of `0` to `plans['Maintain']`:

```py
plans = {
    'Maintain': 0,
    'Fat Loss': -500,
    'Muscle Gain': 350
}

levels = {
    'Low': 12,
    'Low Medium': 13,
    'Medium': 14,
    'Medium High': 15,
    'High': 16
}
```

After that, to do the calculation you want, you need to access the value of the corresponding dictionary key pointed by `plan_var` and `maint_var`. Something like this:

```py
def calculate():
    print(plans[plan_var.get()] + levels[maint_var.get()])
```

The example above just print the sum on the console. If you want to do something else, just `return` that value and deal with it in your code.

Gluing it all together:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def calculate():
    print(plans[plan_var.get()] + levels[maint_var.get()])


plans = {
    'Maintain': 0,
    'Fat Loss': -500,
    'Muscle Gain': 350
}

levels = {
    'Low': 12,
    'Low Medium': 13,
    'Medium': 14,
    'Medium High': 15,
    'High': 16
}

root = tk.Tk()

plan = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a plan: ', justify=tk.RIGHT)
plan.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=5)
plan_var = tk.StringVar(root)
plan_var.set('Maintain')
plan_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, plan_var, *plans)
plan_dropdown.grid(column=4, row=5)

agg = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a level: ', justify=tk.RIGHT)
agg.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=7)
maint_var = tk.StringVar(root)
maint_var.set('Low')
maint_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, maint_var, *levels)
maint_dropdown.grid(column=4, row=7)

submit = tk.Button(root, text='Calculate', command=calculate)
submit.grid(column=4, row=9)

root.mainloop()
```